# Data table has vector as an entry - how to find out in which column and then only take the second entry of vector as a single integer

Tags: r, vector, data.table

I have a data table `tmp`, which can look like this (just a short example):

```
dput(tmp)
structure(list(`2020-03-29-00` = list(42.51, 0, 0, 0, 12.32), 
    `2020-03-29-01` = list(46.8, 0, 0, 0, 10.03), `2020-03-29-03` = list(
        c(46.8, 41.87), c(0, 0), c(0, 0), c(0, 0), c(10.03, 10.04
        )), `2020-03-29-04` = list(45.63, 0, 0, 0, 9.24), `2020-03-29-05` = list(
        40.86, 0, 0, 0, 9.06), `2020-03-29-06` = list(45.85, 
        0, 0, 0, 9.19), `2020-03-29-07` = list(43.68, 0, 0, 0, 
        10.39), `2020-03-29-08` = list(47.14, 0, 0, 0, 9.99), 
    `2020-03-29-09` = list(49.06, 0, 0, 0, 11.24)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000015baf701ef0>)
```

Here we can see, that the third column ("`2020-03-29-03`") has vector entries. What I want is to take the second entry of this vector as a single integer entry. The vector-column (here: third column) isn't always on the same column-index. So, first we need to find out the place where the entry is a vector and then only taking the second entry of this vector.

In the end my data table should look like this:

```
structure(list(`2020-03-29-00` = list(42.51, 0, 0, 0, 12.32), 
    `2020-03-29-01` = list(46.8, 0, 0, 0, 10.03), `2020-03-29-03` = list(
        c(41.87), 0, 0, 0, c(10.04)), 
    `2020-03-29-04` = list(45.63, 0, 0, 0, 9.24), `2020-03-29-05` = list(
        40.86, 0, 0, 0, 9.06), `2020-03-29-06` = list(45.85, 
        0, 0, 0, 9.19), `2020-03-29-07` = list(43.68, 0, 0, 0, 
        10.39), `2020-03-29-08` = list(47.14, 0, 0, 0, 9.99), 
    `2020-03-29-09` = list(49.06, 0, 0, 0, 11.24)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000015baf701ef0>)
```

Comment: I have upvoted the question because it included a [mcve] and provided the input data as well as the expected result in `dput()` format. Otherwise, I wouldn't had been able to find out about the list structure of all columns. I wish all posted questions would be like that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect `tmp` using `str(tmp)` or `lapply(tmp, class)` you will notice that *all* columns are list columns, even those where the vectors contain only one element.

Also, this can be disclosed by setting the appropriate print option

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)
tmp
```

> ```
>    2020-03-29-00 2020-03-29-01 2020-03-29-03 2020-03-29-04 2020-03-29-05 2020-03-29-06 2020-03-29-07 2020-03-29-08 2020-03-29-09
>           <list>        <list>        <list>        <list>        <list>        <list>        <list>        <list>        <list>
> 1:         42.51          46.8   46.80,41.87         45.63         40.86         45.85         43.68         47.14         49.06
> 2:             0             0           0,0             0             0             0             0             0             0
> 3:             0             0           0,0             0             0             0             0             0             0
> 4:             0             0           0,0             0             0             0             0             0             0
> 5:         12.32         10.03   10.03,10.04          9.24          9.06          9.19         10.39          9.99         11.24
> ```

So, in case that *all* list columns need to be coerced to numeric we can pick the *last value* in each vector (which happens to be the second vector entry in column 3) by using the `last()` function:

```
tmp[, lapply(.SD, \(x) sapply(x, last)), .SDcols = is.list]
```

> ```
>    2020-03-29-00 2020-03-29-01 2020-03-29-03 2020-03-29-04 2020-03-29-05 2020-03-29-06 2020-03-29-07 2020-03-29-08 2020-03-29-09
>            <num>         <num>         <num>         <num>         <num>         <num>         <num>         <num>         <num>
> 1:         42.51         46.80         41.87         45.63         40.86         45.85         43.68         47.14         49.06
> 2:          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00
> 3:          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00
> 4:          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00
> 5:         12.32         10.03         10.04          9.24          9.06          9.19         10.39          9.99         11.24
> ```

Now, all columns are numeric.

Comment: @MikiK, thank you for the feedback. Please, try `function(x)` instead of `\(x)`. `\(x)` is new with R version 4.1.0. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Thank you, @TarJae. Very kind, but compliments go to MikiK as well because the question included the input data in `dput()` format instead of some spurious table format (or even worse as a screenshot). Without this I wouldn't had been able to find out about the list structure of all columns.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
This is a very fast solution. 
My original data has around 414 rows and 8784 columns. The ``for``-loop doesn't give me a result in hours.

Answer (score 3):

try `apply` in loop by cols

```
for (col in colnames(tmp)) {
  tmp[,col] <- apply(tmp[,..col], 1, function(x) {
    # mean(unlist(x), na.rm = TRUE) ## if you want mean insted of second entry of this vector
    ifelse(is.na(unlist(x)[2]), unlist(x)[1], unlist(x)[2])
    }  
  )  
}
```

or just `apply`

```
tmp <- apply(tmp, c(1,2), function(x) {
  # mean(unlist(x), na.rm = TRUE)
  ifelse(is.na(unlist(x)[2]), unlist(x)[1], unlist(x)[2])
  } 
) %>% as.data.table() ## convert to data.table from matrix
```

Comment: Please, note that the second variant `tmp <- apply(...` returns a matrix instead of a data.table object. As Patrick Burns says in chapter 8.2.38 of his book [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) _The `apply` function often doesn’t do what is desired because it coerces the data frame to a matrix
before proceeding._

Answer (score 3):

a quick and dirty method:

```
as.data.table(lapply(dt, \(x){
  if(length(x) == sum(lengths(x)))
    x
  else
    sapply(x, \(y)y[[2]])
}))
```

Alternative, but using the in-place aspect of data.tables

```
for(i in names(dt)[sapply(dt, \(x)sum(lengths(x)) != length(x))]){
  set(dt, j = i, value = sapply(dt[[i]], \(y)y[[2]]))
}
```

Note that I use the new lambda function asepcts in R 4.1.0. Before you would have to use `function(x)` and `function(y)` in place of `\(x)` and `\(y)`.

Answer (score 2):

This solution should be robust enough to handle your problem.
It does automatically check, which cols need to be cleaned. If you want to specify certain rows, just change up `cols_contain_vec` to an vector of column indices.

```r
# Find the relevant cols which contain vectors
# which cols contain max lengths over 1?
cols_contain_vec <- which(apply(tmp, MARGIN = 2,function(x) max(lengths(x))) > 1)



tmp[,cols_contain_vec] <- apply(
  tmp[,cols_contain_vec, with = FALSE],
  # separate function call for every row (1) and column(2)
  MARGIN = c(1,2),
  function(x) { # Return second entry if possible, for some reason the vectors are saved
                # as lists, so we have to unlist them
    relevant_vec <- unlist(x)
    if(length(relevant_vec)>1){
      # if vector length over 1, return second element
      return(relevant_vec[[2]])
    } else {
      # if vector length is below 2 then return the first value
      return(relevant_vec[[1]])
    }
  })
)
```

This results in the following:

```r
> tmp
   2020-03-29-00 2020-03-29-01 2020-03-29-03 2020-03-29-04 2020-03-29-05 2020-03-29-06
1:         42.51          46.8         41.87         45.63         40.86         45.85
2:             0             0          0.00             0             0             0
3:             0             0          0.00             0             0             0
4:             0             0          0.00             0             0             0
5:         12.32         10.03         10.04          9.24          9.06          9.19
   2020-03-29-07 2020-03-29-08 2020-03-29-09
1:         43.68         47.14         49.06
2:             0             0             0
3:             0             0             0
4:             0             0             0
5:         10.39          9.99         11.24
```

I hope this helps.